# Karma - can I use script tags instead of karma.config.files?

Tags: javascript, tdd, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Karma offers a config option called `customContextFile`, which allows the user to specify the HTML file that Karma will serve.

**My question is -** Can I add `<script>` tags directly to the custom context file? Or do I have to use the `files` property in the karma config to load files in the browser?

---

#### more info

I want to put script tags directly on my customContextFile so that it looks similar to index.html, with all the vendor files listed, etc.

However, karma is listing 404s for the script tags I have added to the custom context file. I suspect this is because I don't have these files listed in the karma config's files property. Or maybe my path is wrong in the script tags?

**directory structure**

```
.
|--app
|   |--mock
|   |   |--*.json
|   |--scripts
|   |   |--*.ts
|   |--vendor
|   |   |--*.js
|
|--config
|   |--karma.conf.js
|
|--dist
|   |--mock
|   |   |--*.json
|   |--scripts
|   |   |--*.js
|   |--tests
|   |   |--*.js
|   |--vendor
|   |   |--*.js
|   |--specRunner.html
|
```

**config/karma.conf.js**

```
config.set({
    basePath: '../dist',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['dots'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: false,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
    plugins: [
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    customContextFile: 'specRunner.html',

    files: [
        {pattern: 'vendor/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
        {pattern: 'mock/**/*.json', included: false, watched: false},
        {pattern: 'scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
        {pattern: 'tests/**/*.js', included: false}
    ]
    ...
```

**dist/specRunner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spec Runner</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Thank you for reading this far</h1>

<h2>Karma 404s with each of these</h2>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/vendor/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

...etc...

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/x.module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/y.module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/z.module.js"></script>

...etc...  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `files` option in the Karma configuration performs multiple jobs. One of its jobs is to tell Karma what `script` element to create. However, another one of its jobs is to tell Karma what scripts to serve. You cannot just manually put `script` elements in your HTML and call it done. You need to configure Karma so that the files will be served because if they are not listed there, Karma won't serve them.

You could have patterns like this in your configuration to tell Karma to serve the files but not include them (`included: false`) as `script` elements on the page:

```
files: [
  { pattern: "vendor/**/*.js", included: false },
  { pattern: "scripts/**/*.js", included: false },
  // ...
]
```

Also node that everything will be served under `/base` on the browser side. So the file `scripts/app.js` will be served as `/base/scripts/app.js` and this latter path is the one you must use in `script` or whenever you refer to that file.

If you are ever confused about what it is that Karma sees and how it serves it, you can go into debug mode in the browser and inspect the variable `__karma__.files`. It is an map of file names that Karma is able to serve: the keys are the file names, and the value for each key is a checksum of the contents of the file.

Comment: `included: false, served: true` makes sense. Thanks! But do you know the proper path for the script tags? Karma can't find the scripts I'm requesting in the HTML.